# Get Users Name and Email from WindowsIdentity on local

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication, intranet

I'm trying to build a webapp to be deployed on our intranet. I'm at the stage where I want to user information.

To my knowledge I've set up authentication correctly by implementing:

in Startup->ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

and in Startup->Configure:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Now in a model for a page I've been trying to get user info and I can't seem to get past userName and Groups.

```
    public void OnGet()
    {

        var wi = (WindowsIdentity)User.Identity;

        this.email = wi.Claims.FirstOrDefault(
            c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
        this.claimsCount = wi.Claims.Count().ToString();
        this.claims = wi.Claims.Select(x => x.Type.ToString()).ToList();
        this.authenticationType= wi.AuthenticationType.ToString();
        this.name = wi.Name;

        if (wi.Groups != null)
            foreach (var group in wi.Groups)
            {

                try
                {
                    this.groups.Add(group.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // ignored
                }
            }

    }
```

This is what I get in my model after.

```
this.email = null
this.claimsCount = 51
this.claims = {A list composed of claims/name, claims/primarysid, claims/primarygroupsid, claims/groupsid x 48}
this.authenticationType = Negotiate 
this.name = my login username
```

How do I go about getting the users e-mail address and Given Name (ie: "John Doe" not "CA/jdoe") from here? My research leads me to believe that I might not have permission on my local computer to get this information.

If this is the case how do I go and check the deployment server to see if it has the permission required to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

1) I was a missing a package/Reference named System.DirectoryServices that I was able to get using NuGet.

2) I added the following lines of code.

```
        var wi = (WindowsIdentity)User.Identity;

        System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry user = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://<SID={wi.User.Value}>");

        user.RefreshCache(new[] { "givenName", "sn" });

        this.name = user.Properties["givenName"].Value.ToString();
```